# Visual Studio Code Unable to Fetch Definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get intellisense using Visual Studio Code.

Error:

> Unable to fetch d.ts file at
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts:
>   [object Object]

I get the error above when right clicking the $ in `$("#element").addClass("class")`; and hovering over the underlined message and clicking on "Download type definition jquery.d.ts"

I have not found anyone with this error in any forums.

Visual Studio Code Version : 0.7.10
Windows 7 Enterprise - Service Pack 1

Comment: please provide sample of code

Comment: @Artiom this is about a tool error, not about a specific code issue

Comment: Why not install the typescript definition through nuget?  https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=TypeScript